# How to access json value inside reduce function in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

my reduce function in Couchbase[just for testing] :

```
function(keys,values,reduce){
return values[0];
}
```

The result is here

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":{"doctype":"closed_auctions","buyer":"person14108"}}
]
}
```

I would like to get individual value inside reduce for further process so when I try to get value of doctype like `values[0].doctype` it returns `null` even though there should be "closed_auctions". what is the problem? How can I get individual value(I mean field value) inside reduce function.

Comment: Please provide your Map function code here also.

Answer (score 3):

Your reduce function called after map performed. Also remember that re-reduce also called and at that time your result is further aggregated. You should use "group=true" when running this view.

So, sometimes values[0] might not have document

You need to check for existence of the property/doc first, e.g.

```
function(keys, values, rereduce)
{
  if (values[0] && values[0].doctype)
  {
    return values[0].doctype;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

See also: [9.5.2.4. Writing Custom Reduce Functions](http://www.couchbase.com/docs//couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-reduce.html#couchbase-views-writing-reduce-custom)